# how can move from one tabviewcontroller to another tabviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone

I've a problem that when I  go to any viewcontroller of second tabbar button then I need to come first tabviewcontroller. but i can't in my one view of first tabbar comes to second tabbar button.pls someone help me.

Comment: Can you explain the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; 
// or 1 or 2 for other tabs
```